# Regex a number at the end of a url after a underscore with Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to `match` the '12345' from a url in this form:

http://domain.com/folder/title_of_this_12345

So far I've tried:

```
var pattern = "_([0-9]+)^";

alert(window.location.pathname.match(pattern));
```

but I'm just returned with null?

The aim is to regex the numbers from the end of the string to the first underscore?

Comment: @nhahtdh how would I do it with those? I'm not too familiar with all the Javascript functions

Comment: I'd probably do something like `var num = url.split('_').pop()`

Comment: Damn, that's a pretty awesome way to do it.

Comment: @GGG: How would you extract the number? parseFloat and Number() are what pop in my mind, but they will return NaN for non-number string, which we have to detect with an ugly `if (num != num)` statement.

Comment: @nhahtdh personally, I'd do `var num = +url.split('_').pop()`. Some people don't like unary plus operator for type conversion though.

Comment: @GGG: I think you should post your comment as answer.

Comment: @nhahtdh but the OP wanted regex...

Comment: @GGG: Personally, I consider any good solution, regardless of the method, that reaches the same result (or a better result) an answer to the question (unless the restriction is absolute). Anyway, I don't want to force my opinion on you, so it's your choice to post an answer or not.

Comment: @nhahtdh the thing is, split/pop is probably less performant than substring, which is probably less performant than regex. So if performance is critical, you'd probably want regex. Split/pop is kind of a lazy shortcut.

Comment: @GGG So the fastest way to do this is the regex method?

Comment: @Silver89 probably, you could test it if you want. In your case since you're doing it with a URL, we can assume you're only doing it once or maybe a handful of times per page load, not thousands of times or anything, so performance probably doesn't really matter for you right now. It seemed like you needed help with regex, though, which is why I didn't write a non-regex answer. Anyway, yeah, regex is pretty fast, every time I perf stuff like this regex wins.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you replace the `^` with `$`, your method will work. `^` matches beginning of the string, while `$` matches the end of the string (although not relevant here, please check documentation on the behavior of `$` when there is presence of new line character).

Non-regex solution is possible, but if the link may or may not contain the number, your would have to either check the last token is a number or check whether result of parsing is NaN. So regex probably is the appropriate solution here.

Comment: I also find `\d` more readable than `[0-9]`, but that's just me. +1

Answer (score 2):

Just to be clear, the matched number itself is retrieved at index 1 of the returned array:

```
alert(str.match(/_(\d+)$/)[1]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
var path = window.location.pathname;
var num = parseInt(path.substr(path.lastIndexOf('_') + 1, 10));
```

as an alternative not involving regexps.

Actually, see GGG's comment on the question for a much more concise non-regexp way to do it.

Comment: If the token is not number, then there can be problems.